# change name on wicket application

Tags: jakarta-ee, wicket, pom.xml

As said I want to change the name of a wicket application. Preferably I would like to set the name in pom.xml so it will be consistent through versions. Right now it looks something like this:

> localhost:port/artifactId-version

what i want is

> localhost:port/artifactId

Thanks

Comment: You run your app in Tomcat or JBOSS?

Comment: JBoss, but I would like to have the same functionality in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building your Wicket app via Maven and creating a WAR file of the form 'artifactId-version.war' and the servlet engine's using that as the deployed name, one option would be to set the ${project.build.finalName} property in the pom to be ${project.artifactId} (or the 'warName' value in the war plugin config).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you are looking for but maybe ok for you. We do it in JBOSS 5.1 in the jboss-web.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/yourName</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

The jboss-web.xml file is placed alongside web.xml.

Comment: That does the trick! Is it possible to do this in some general way for the most common servers?

Comment: I dont know. We only use JBOSS.